# Multiple TextView on a Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to create a ListView with 2 `TextView`. I'm not very good in Java so I usually follow many tutorials and combine them to create what I need.

But I've tried to combine 2 guides together without much success...

Here is the tutorial I'm trying to follow to add the second `TextView` :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_3104328239&feature=iv&src_vid=8K-6gdTlGEA&v=E6vE8fqQPTE

But this doesn't really help me since I have difficulty understanding how I can implement what he is doing.

So far what I have understood is that I need to add my item like this :

```
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Électron","1/6"));
```

To do so I'll have to modify EntryItem and my class that extends `BaseAdapter`

But I haven't been successful with that.

What is the best way to add my second `TextView`?

Fragment Activity

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

ListView lvCountry;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);

        lvCountry = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvCountry);

        ArrayList<Item> countryList = new ArrayList<Tab1Fragment.Item>();
        // Header
    countryList.add(new SectionItem("Atomes")); // 0
    // State Name
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Électron")); // 1
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Monstre")); // 2
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Neutron")); //3
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Proton")); //4
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Stigmate")); //5

    // Header
    countryList.add(new SectionItem("Chaos")); //6
    // State Name
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Casbah")); //7
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Chaos")); //8
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Gaufrette"));//9
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Lorenz")); //10

    // Header
    countryList.add(new SectionItem("Monolith")); //11
    // State Name
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Chanceux")); //12
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Monolith")); //13
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Ubik")); //14

    // Header
    countryList.add(new SectionItem("Autres")); //15
    // State Name
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Beau")); //16
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Enclume")); //17
    countryList.add(new EntryItem("Huitre")); //18

    // set adapter
        final CountryAdapter adapter = new CountryAdapter(getActivity(), countryList);
        lvCountry.setAdapter(adapter);

    com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton fab = (com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.attachToListView(lvCountry);

    lvCountry.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            int i = 0;
            for (i= 0; i < 16 ; i++) {


                if(position== 0||position==6||position==11||position==15){


                }
                else {
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myintent, i);
                }


            }
        }
    });

        lvCountry.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // filter on text change



    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });
    return view;
}





    /**
     * row item
     */
    public interface Item {
        public boolean isSection();
        public String getTitle();
    }

    /**
     * Section Item
     */
    public class SectionItem implements Item {
        private final String title;

        public SectionItem(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSection() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Entry Item
     */
    public class EntryItem implements Item {
        public final String title;

        public EntryItem(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSection() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter
     */
    public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Item> item;
        private ArrayList<Item> originalItem;

        public CountryAdapter(Tab1Fragment tab1Fragment, ArrayList<Item> countryList) {
            super();
        }

        public CountryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> item) {
            this.context = context;
            this.item = item;
            //this.originalItem = item;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return item.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return item.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (item.get(position).isSection()) {
                // if section header
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_section, parent, false);
                TextView tvSectionTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSectionTitle);
                tvSectionTitle.setText(((SectionItem) item.get(position)).getTitle());
            }
            else
            {
                // if item
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item, parent, false);
                TextView tvItemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemTitle);
                tvItemTitle.setText(((EntryItem) item.get(position)).getTitle());
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        /**
         * Filter
         */
        public Filter getFilter()
        {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                    item = (ArrayList<Item>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("null")
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<Item> filteredArrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();


                    if(originalItem == null || originalItem.size() == 0)
                    {
                        originalItem = new ArrayList<Item>(item);
                    }

                /*
                 * if constraint is null then return original value
                 * else return filtered value
                 */
                    if(constraint == null && constraint.length() == 0)
                    {
                        results.count = originalItem.size();
                        results.values = originalItem;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                        for (int i = 0; i < originalItem.size(); i++)
                        {
                            String title = originalItem.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                            if(title.startsWith(constraint.toString()))
                            {
                                filteredArrayList.add(originalItem.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        results.count = filteredArrayList.size();
                        results.values = filteredArrayList;
                    }

                    return results;
                }
            };

            return filter;
        }
    }

}
```

Layout_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="80">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1/6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[This is what the App looks like for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VNh0.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

*You found a grammar mistake? Don't keep it to yourself ! English isn't my mother tongue. Share it, so I can correct myself !*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to modify your `EntryItem` by adding a field to indicate the value, like this:

```
public class EntryItem implements Item {

    public final String title;
    public final String value;

    public EntryItem(String title, String value) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, you have to get the `TextView` reference of your `TextView` of id `textView2` and `setText()` inside `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` of your Adapter.

```
if (item.get(position).isSection()) {
    //your code...
} else {
    //your code...
    TextView tvItemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tvItemTitle.setText(((EntryItem) item.get(position)).getValue());
}
```

Finally, update your `EntryItem` data:

```
countryList.add(new SectionItem("Atomes")); // 0
// State Name
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Électron", "1/6")); // 1
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Monstre", "1/6")); // 2
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Neutron", "1/6")); //3
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Proton", "1/6")); //4
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Stigmate", "1/6")); //5

// Header
countryList.add(new SectionItem("Chaos")); //6
// State Name
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Casbah", "1/6")); //7
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Chaos", "1/6")); //8
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Gaufrette", "1/6"));//9
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Lorenz", "1/6")); //10

// Header
countryList.add(new SectionItem("Monolith")); //11
// State Name
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Chanceux", "1/6")); //12
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Monolith", "1/6")); //13
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Ubik", "1/6")); //14

// Header
countryList.add(new SectionItem("Autres")); //15
// State Name
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Beau", "1/6")); //16
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Enclume", "1/6")); //17
countryList.add(new EntryItem("Huitre", "1/6")); //18
```